# Get Random Response from list by weight

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I need to get multiple random response from `response=` list without duplicates.

So when someone types `!pick` bot gives random picks from `responses list`.

```
example like Quiz top rank 1, 2, 3 and 4 to 10 :
when used `!pick` command

bot reply's 
Top 1 'Eagle'
Top 2 'Apple'
Top 3 'Elephant'
Top 4 'Cat'
Top 5 'Bear'
Top 6 'Snake'
Top 7 'Deer'
Top 8 'Rhino'
Top 9 'Crocodile'
Top 10 'Lion'
```

---

Update

```
responses = [(60, ("One", "Five", "Seven")), (30, ("Two", "Four", "Six")), (10, ("Three", "Eight"))]
total = sum(w for w, vals in responses)
vals, weights = zip(*[(val, (w/len(vals))/total) for w, vals in responses for val in vals])

@bot.command(pass_context=True)  
async def pick(k : int):
    chosen = choice(vals, size=8, replace=False, p=weights)
    a, b, c = chosen[:2], chosen[:2], chosen[:4]
    embed = discord.Embed(description='\n'.join(b))
    await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`random.choices`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) can take a list of weights.

```
responses = [(60, ("One", "Five", "Seven")), (30, ("Two", "Four", "Six")), (10, ("Three", "Eight"))]
vals, weights = zip(*[(val, w/len(vals)) for w, vals in responses for val in vals])

@bot.command()  
async def pick(k : int):
    if 0 <= k <= 10:
        embed = discord.Embed(description='\n'.join(random.choices(vals, weights=weights, k=k)))
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Here's a version using `numpy.random.choice`

```
responses = [(60, ("One", "Five", "Seven")), (30, ("Two", "Four", "Six")), (10, ("Three", "Eight"))]
total = sum(w for w, vals in responses)
vals, weights = zip(*[(val, (w/len(vals))/total) for w, vals in responses for val in vals])

@bot.command(pass_context=True)  
async def pick(k : int):
    for x in zip(*[iter(choice(vals, size=6, replace=False, p=weights))]*2):
        embed = discord.Embed(description='\n'.join(x))
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Here's the a, b,c version:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)  
async def pick(k : int):
    chosen = choice(vals, size=8, replace=False, p=weights)
    a, b, c = chosen[:2], chosen[2:4], chosen[4:]
    for x in (a, b, c): 
        embed = discord.Embed(description='\n'.join(x))
        await bot.say(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Either do them one after another, or loop over them.

Comment: @Bosen I didn't cathc a mistake you made with your slices.  If you want 2, 2, 4, the slices should be `a, b, c = chosen[:2], chosen[2:4], chosen[4:]`

Comment: Thank you it worked.what is d formula if i need to keep changing that number everytime?

Comment: Ok i practised Slicing number its working fine for different numbers. but 1 last question if there is only 1 word in `(60, ("One"))` rather than 2 or more in `(60, ("One", "Five"))` result will give single letter like  `o`  ,  `n`   ,  `e` like by line single letter. can i know y this happens.

Comment: `("One")` evaluates to the string `"One"`.  If you want a tuple of length 1, you need a trailing comma: `("One",)`